# Convert ordered comma separated list into tuples with ordered element number (a la SQL SPLIT_STRING) using C# 6.0/.Net Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, split

I can't seem to find a ready answer to this, or even if the question has ever been asked before, but I want functionality similar to the SQL STRING_SPLIT functions floating around, where each item in a comma separated list is identified by its ordinal in the string.

Given the string "abc,xyz,def,tuv", I want to get a list of tuples like:

```
<1, "abc">
<2, "xyz">
<3, "def">
<4, "tuv">
```

Order is important, and I need to preserve the order, and be able to take the list and further join it with another list using linq, and be able to preserve the order. For example, if a second list is <"tuv", "abc">, I want the final output of the join to be:

```
<1, "abc">
<4, "tuv">
```

Basically, I want the comma separated string to determine the ORDER of the end result, where the comma separated string contains ALL possible strings, and it is joined with an unordered list of a subset of strings, and the output is a list of ordered tuples that consists only of the elements in the second list, but in the order determined by the comma separated string at the beginning.

I could likely figure out all of this on my own if I could just get a C# equivalent to all the various SQL STRING_SPLIT functions out there, which do the split but also include the ordinal element number in the output. But I've searched, and I find nothing for C# but splitting a string into individual elements, or splitting them into tuples where both elements of the tuple are in the string itself, not generated integers to preserve order.

The order is the important thing to me here. So if an element number isn't readily possible, a way to inner join two lists and guarantee preserving the order of the first list while returning only those elements in the second list would be welcome. The tricky part for me is this last part: the result of a join needs a specific (not easy to sort by) order. The ordinal number would give me something to sort by, but if I can inner join with some guarantee the output is in the same order as the first input, that'd work too.

Comment: may i know how big( i mean 10,20, or 1000) could be items in  comma separated string?

Comment: Less than a 2000, more than 50. An average of around 800 is to be assumed

Comment: instead of loop LINQ is better in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work on .NET framework.

```
using System.Linq;
string str = "abc,xyz,def,tuv";
string str2 = "abc,tuv";


IEnumerable< PretendFileObject> secondList = str2.Split(',').Select(x=> new PretendFileObject() { FileName = x}); //

var tups = str.Split(',')
    .Select((x, i) => { return (i + 1, x); })
    .Join(secondList, //Join Second list ON 
    item => item.Item2 //This is the filename in the tuples 
    ,item2 => item2.FileName, // This is the filename property for a given object in the second list to join on
    (item,item2) => new {Index = item.Item1,FileName = item.Item2, Obj = item2})
    .OrderBy(JoinedObject=> JoinedObject.Index)
    .ToList();

foreach (var tup in tups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tup.Obj.FileName);
}


public class PretendFileObject
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Original Response Below

If you wanted to stick to something SQL like here is how to do it with linq operators. The Select method has a built in index param you can make use of. And you can use IntersectBy to perform an easy inner join.

```
using System.Linq;
string str = "abc,xyz,def,tuv";
string str2 = "abc,tuv";
var secondList = str2.Split(',');

var tups = str.Split(',')
    .Select((x, i) => { return (i + 1, x); })
    .IntersectBy(secondList, s=>s.Item2) //Filter down to only the strings found in both.
    .ToList();

foreach(var tup in tups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tup);
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but unfortunately it requires .Net Framework 6 or later and I'm stuck on legacy code with .Net Framework 4.8 (the "intersectby" method isn't available). But this answer did help me focus better on my question and how I may have simplified it too far (or not been clear enough). Think of the second list as a list of objects, like file objects. I want to iterate over the second list in the ORDER determined by the first list, matching the strings to, say, the "FileName" property. So your answer is REALLY close, but for C# 6.0 and up environments I can't use here.

Comment: I guess a clearer statement of my issue is that I want to join the two lists on listOne.string = listTwo.Filename, and then iterate over the result by listOne.index so that I can process all the file objects in the correct order set by listOne.

Comment: The update is exactly what I need. Thanks. This was really informative.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you list of tuples

```cs
var input = "abc,xyz,def,tuv";
string[] items = input.Split(',');
var tuples = new List<(int, string)>();
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length)
{
    tuples.Add(((i + 1), items[i]));
}
```

if then you want to add list of `"tuv"` and `"abc"` and keep 1, you probably want to "Left Join". But I am not sure, how you can do using LINQ because you first need to iterate the original list of tuples and assign same `int`. Then join. Or, you can join first and then assign `int` but technically, order is not guaranteed. However, if you assign `int` first, you can sort by it in the end.

I am slightly confused by *"and be able to take the list and further join it with another list using linq"*. Join usually means aggregate result. But in your case it seem you demanding segment, not joined data.

--

*"I want to remove any items from the second list that are not in the first list, and then I need to iterate over the second list IN THE ORDER of the first list"*

```cs
var input2 = "xxx,xyz,yyy,tuv,";
string[] items2 = input2.Split(',');

IEnumerable<(int, string)> finalTupleOutput = 
    tuples.Join(items2, t => t.Item2, i2 => i2, (t, i2) => (t.Item1, i2)).OrderBy(tpl => tpl.Item1);
```

This will give you what you want - matching items from `L2` in the order from `L1`

Comment: This is an interesting solution to half the issue. I think it mostly gives me what I want/need. To clarify on the second part, I have a second list. I want to remove any items from the second list that are not in the first list, and then I need to iterate over the second list IN THE ORDER of the first list. In SQL, an inner join would give me a result where I'd have the ordinal from the first list, and the matching string from the second, and I could then sort on the ordinal to produce a list to iterate over. Make more sense?

Comment: @pmbAustin See update. Solved

Answer (score 1):

with LINQ

```
string inputString = "abc,xyz,def,tuv";
var output = inputString.Split(',')
.Select((item, index) => { return (index + 1, item); });
```

now you can use the `output` list as you want to use.

Comment: This is a nice, easy to understand, succinct solution to the first half of my problem. Thank you. This was educational (I'm not great at linq yet).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're after, but here's an attempt:

```
string[] vals = new[] { "abc", "xyz", "dev", "tuv"};

string[] results = new string[vals.Length];

int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++)
{
    results[i] = $"<{++index},\"{vals[i]}\">";
}

foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This produces:

```
<1,"abc">
<2,"xyz">
<3,"dev">
<4,"tuv">
```

Comment: I think this answer is a little too literal... I wanted an output of tuples, not an output of a single string list. Think of it as I wanted the output to be a list of structs { int Ordinal, string Value}, so that I could easily sort by the ordinal if I needed to, in order to get the proper ordering. This answer just gives me a list of strings where the ordinal is embedded in the string, not a separate value.

Comment: Change the type of results to any type you desire. The principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Given the example

> For example, if a second list is <"tuv", "abc">, I want the final
> output of the join to be:
>
> <1, "abc"> <4, "tuv">

I think this might be close?

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>() { "abc", "def", "xyz", "tuv" };
List<string> temp2 = new List<string>() { "dbc", "ace", "zyw", "tke", "abc", "xyz" };
var intersect = temp.Intersect(temp2).Select((list, idx) => (idx+1, list));
```

This produces an intersect result that has the elements from list 1 that are also in list 2, which in this case would be:

```
<1, "abc">
<2, "xyz">
```

If you want *all* the elements from both lists, switch the `Intersect` to `Union`.